# Error during node.js package install. Hummusjs

Tags: node.js, npm, hummus.js

I am unable to install the package with the command

```
npm install -g hummus
```

The error from the logs is:

```
1926 verbose stack Error: hummus@1.0.87 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
1926 verbose stack Exit status 1
1926 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
1926 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
1926 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
1926 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
1926 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
1926 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
1926 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
1926 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
1927 verbose pkgid hummus@1.0.87
1928 verbose cwd C:\Users\name\Downloads\lab\data\docs\hummusjs
1929 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
1930 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "hummus"
1931 verbose node v8.9.4
1932 verbose npm  v5.6.0
1933 error code ELIFECYCLE
1934 error errno 1
1935 error hummus@1.0.87 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
1935 error Exit status 1
1936 error Failed at the hummus@1.0.87 install script.
1936 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
1937 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The output from the command line is:

```
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://hummus.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hummus/v1.0.87/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for hummus@1.0.87 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
The system cannot find the path specified.
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\hummus\\binding\\hummus.node" "--module_name=hummus" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\hummus\\binding" "--napi_version=1" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus\binding\hummus.node --module_name=hummus --module_path=C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus\binding --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\hummus\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus\binding\hummus.node --module_name=hummus --module_path=C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus\binding --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hummus@1.0.87 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hummus@1.0.87 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-23T13_48_48_779Z-debug.log
```

I am new to node.js and have no idea what these messages are saying. The paths printed in the lines

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\hummus\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
```

and

```
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus\binding\hummus.node --module_name=hummus --module_path=C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hummus\binding --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
```

in the command line output don't exist on my drive:

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
```

doesn't exist.

I tried setting a NODE_PATH environment variable to the path that has a node_modules folder:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
```

But i get the same error.

Comment: node-gyp errors can be a pain, it often comes down to having the right build tools on your computer. You can try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools, but often it can be simpler (at least if you are using nvm already) to just change node-version to a version where where pre-built binaries already exist (you see that 404 warning shows that none exists for that version of node with that version of windows).

Comment: And here is a list of hummus prebuilt binaries: https://hummus.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ (and it seems windows is not even on that list, so no point in changing node version...) So your options are here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `.travis.yml`, these versions have published binaries:

```
NODE_NVM_VERSION="0.12.18"
NODE_NVM_VERSION="4.9.1"
NODE_NVM_VERSION="5.12.0"
NODE_NVM_VERSION="6.14.1"
NODE_NVM_VERSION="7.10.1"
NODE_NVM_VERSION="8.11.1"
NODE_NVM_VERSION="9.11.1"
```

Can you update to Node 8.11.1 (you were using 8.9.4) and try again?